# Rails Migration problem: disk image is malformed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I am trying to add columns to my SQLITE3 database and having some problems.
When I run rake db:migrate in the terminal, I get:

> SQLite3::CorruptException: database
>   disk image is malformed: INSERT INTO
>   "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES
>   ('20110425202452')

Here's the code for adding the columns:

```
    class AddPhotoToItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :items, :preview_photo_file_name, :string 
    add_column :items, :preview_photo_content_type, :string
    add_column :items, :preview_photo_file_size, :integer
    add_column :items, :thumbnail_photo_file_name, :string 
    add_column :items, :thumbnail_photo_content_type, :string
    add_column :items, :thumbnail_photo_file_size, :integer

  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :items, :preview_photo_file_name, :string 
    remove_column :items, :preview_photo_content_type, :string
    remove_column :items, :preview_photo_file_size, :integer
    remove_column :items, :thumbnail_photo_file_name, :string 
    remove_column :items, :thumbnail_photo_content_type, :string
    remove_column :items, :thumbnail_photo_file_size, :integer
  end
end
```

What's the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the sqlite3 file opened by another process?

Answer (score 1):

The database corruption happens `if postfix is running` on your machine.

You don't have to uninstall postfix, but stop the process, so that the db corruption won't happen.

For more info, refer [here.](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6125-sqlite3corruptexception-database-disk-image-is-malformed)

Comment: Hi Jatin, thanks for the answer. I haven't found a way to disable the postfix, do you have any idea how I can do that? Besides, why is it happening? All of the other migrations worked great..